# block scope influencing declarations outside of it

Tags: javascript

```html
<p id="Test1"></p>
<p id="Test2"></p>
<p id="Test3"></p>

<script>
    {
        let v;
        v = 10;
    }

    let g = 20;

    var h = 15;

    document.getElementById('Test1').innerHTML = v;
    document.getElementById('Test2').innerHTML = g;
    document.getElementById('Test3').innerHTML = h;
</script>
```

As far as I learned, the let declared variables, can't be used outside a blocked scope, but if I run the code above, none of the 3 get shown? why is that? the scope ended there right?

Comment: It throws an error because `v` is not defined, precisely because it is block scoped. (if you put update with `v` last you'll see `g` and `h` updated before the error is thrown)

Answer (score 0):

When an error occurs, JavaScript will normally stop and generate an error message. The technical term for this is: JavaScript will throw an exception (throw an error). JavaScript will actually create an Error object with two properties: name and message.
**So here as soon as compiler try to show "v" js compiler throw error **

- Uncaught ReferenceError: v is not defined
  And it terminate execution due to which you can not see that value of g and , h.
  here are two case:
  ** case 1**
  As "v" is commented you can see value of g and h(without error in console).

  ```js
  let g = 20;

  var h = 15; {

    let v;
    v = 10;
  }


  //document.getElementById('Test1').innerHTML = v;
  document.getElementById('Test2').innerHTML = g;
  document.getElementById('Test3').innerHTML = h;
  ```

  ```html
  <p id="Test1"></p>
  <p id="Test2"></p>
  <p id="Test3"></p>
  ```

** CASE 2**
** I tried to access v value as last so now you can see value of g and h as it was executed earlier before the error thrown by compiler.

```js
let g = 20;

var h = 15; {

  let v;
  v = 10;
}



document.getElementById('Test2').innerHTML = g;
document.getElementById('Test3').innerHTML = h;
document.getElementById('Test1').innerHTML = v;
```

```html
<p id="Test1"></p>
<p id="Test2"></p>
<p id="Test3"></p>
```

> JavaScript is a single-threaded language, where only one command executes at a time. It has a Synchronous model of execution, where each line is executed line by line, top to bottom.

Unit and unless there is come function such as **set timeout** or **asynchronized** function. which execues differently.